# Can I project a Grease Pencil animation onto a moving Mesh?

Tags: animation, grease-pencil

I have this cloth simulation here and want to animate a 2D ghost face on top of it using Grease Pencil.

[image]

I've tried simply drawing on top of the surface but I'd have to redraw the face for every single frame and if I want to tweak the simulation later I'd have to redo everything. Idealy I'd like to animate the face on 2s, 3s and have hold frames as well.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I would have unwrapped the mesh before simulation and painted the eyes on a texture...

Comment: But then they can't be animated right? I now pinned the Grease Pencil object to the sphere underneath the cloth and set the drawing surface distance to 0.5. That works surprisingly well but isn't the cleanest solution.

Comment: Well, you need an animated texture in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Blender 3.3 doesn't have any tools to keep your drawing to the moving mesh.

Grease pencil drawings have an issue with weight painting which leads to problems with moving objects. If you really wanted, you could rig the grease pencil drawing with empties or armatures and manually weight paint the drawing. Then you could parent the rig to the moving object. This will be more complicated than your current solution but it's probably the closest way CURRENTLY to get what you're asking for.

Comment: That's the information I was looking for. Thank you!